# How to get the cursor position

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I want to know how to get the cursor position on Windows in c++,

Reasons: I try to move the mouse position on X Y coordinate with the screen information

e.g: i want to set the mouse position in the offset x:576 y:854 on the screen.

The only method that I found for do that is:

```
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE|MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE|MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,x,y,0,0);
```

Normally the flag MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE is to do that but it doesn't work, that's why i try to get the absolute position of the mouse and try to calculate that !

Thank you for your answer !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try [GetCursorPos()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648390%28VS.85%29.aspx).