# Get current cursor position

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to get the current mouse position of the window, and assign it to 2 variables `x` and `y` (co-ordinates relative to the window, not to the screen as a whole).

I'm using Win32 and C++.

And a quick bonus question: how would you go about hiding the cursor/unhiding it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the cursor position](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396576/how-to-get-the-cursor-position)

Answer (score 136, accepted):

You get the cursor position by calling [`GetCursorPos`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648390%28VS.85%29.aspx).

```
POINT p;
if (GetCursorPos(&p))
{
    //cursor position now in p.x and p.y
}
```

This returns the cursor position relative to screen coordinates.  Call [`ScreenToClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162952%28VS.85%29.aspx) to map to window coordinates.

```
if (ScreenToClient(hwnd, &p))
{
    //p.x and p.y are now relative to hwnd's client area
}
```

---

You hide and show the cursor with [`ShowCursor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648396%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

```
ShowCursor(FALSE);//hides the cursor
ShowCursor(TRUE);//shows it again
```

You must ensure that every call to hide the cursor is matched by one that shows it again.

Comment: GetCursorPos retrieves screen coordinates while the question asked explicitly for window coordinates. `ScreenToClient`/`MapWindowPoints` is missing from your answer.

Comment: What happens if the hiding and showing calls are not matched? Does it leave the cursor hidden even after the windows/program is closed?

Comment: If you're working with OpenGL like I was when I found this, you might find [GetClientRect(HWND, LPRECT)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633503(v=vs.85).aspx) as useful as I found this when you are flipping the mouse y coord. Cheers

Answer (score 17):

[GetCursorPos()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getcursorpos) will return to you the x/y if you pass in a pointer to a POINT structure.

Hiding the cursor can be done with [ShowCursor()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-showcursor).