# C++: Why must some functions be placed in if statements?

Tags: c++, function, pointers, position, cursor-position

I'll be referencing this answer: [Get current cursor position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6423729/get-current-cursor-position/6423739#6423739)

The working code:

```
    HWND hwnd;
    POINT p;
    if (GetCursorPos(&p))
    {
        //cursor position now in p.x and p.y

    }
    if (ScreenToClient(hwnd, &p))
    {
        //p.x and p.y are now relative to hwnd's client area
        cout << p.x << p.y;
    }
```

This compiles but crashes when I click in the window:

```
    HWND hwnd;
    POINT p;
    if (GetCursorPos(&p) && ScreenToClient(hwnd, &p))
    {
        //cursor position now in p.x and p.y
        cout << p.x << p.y;
    }
```

This also compiles but crashes when I click in the window:

```
    HWND hwnd;
    POINT p;
    GetCursorPos(&p);
    if (ScreenToClient(hwnd, &p))
    {
        //cursor position now in p.x and p.y
        cout << p.x << p.y;
    }
```

Why? Are these functions unusual in any way?

Does it have something to do with the fact that pointers are involved?

How does placing these functions in `if` statements change how they run?

Comment: I'd suspect you've met some stack corruption or so. Rearanging the code can easily hide the errorneous behavior, or expose it.

Comment: In code shown program should not crash any way, looks like problem is somewhere else

Comment: That will crash of course, because hwnd is undefined.

Comment: `hwnd` is undefined, are you sure this is complete code?

Comment: No, I'm not sure at all. Defining a HWND wasn't even shown in the answer I linked, but I placed that there and it compiles.

Comment: @AaronFranke The `HwND hwnd;` is uninitialized. As I guessed you have undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if (GetCursorPos(&p) && ScreenToClient(hwnd, &p))` is quite pernicious, but strangely elegant.

Due to the *short-circutting* nature of the `&&` operator, `ScreenToClient(hwnd, &p)` will only be called if `GetCursorPos(&p)` runs successfully (i.e. returns something that converts to `true`). The latter, if successful, also happens to set `p` to something valid for the subsequent `ScreenToClient` call.

The enclosing `if` block is only ran if *both* functions are successful.

Your crash could well be due to your `hwnd` being uninitialised.

Comment: However, as OP says, `if (GetCursorPos(&p) && ScreenToClient(hwnd, &p))` still crashes when he clicks the window

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't change how the functions run. Many functions return a boolean value indicating whether the operation succeeded or not. By enclosing the function call in an if, you're automatically checking if the operation succeeded.

```
   if(functionReturningSuccess(params))
   {
      //assume the operation succeeded
   }
   else
   {
      //report error
   }
```

Comment: How does this answer why `if (GetCursorPos(&p) && ScreenToClient(hwnd, &p))` crashes when it does not if it is two separate if blocks?

Comment: @NathanOliver there are many questions in the question. This appears to be an answer to another of the questions, than you refer to.