# Can I get the position of selected text in console window (C++)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

[image]

Hello. I am making checkers with C++ for a console window. Currently the only method of interacting is by entering the coordinates of the piece you want to move and then the the coordinates of the place you want to move it. This gets very tedious very fast. I was thinking of somehow getting the coordinates of the selected letter (the 'w' in the image) from the console. I have tried Googling this but I don't know how to word this query properly and haven't found anything yet. Is this possible? If not can you point me some alternative?

Comment: This will be a lot easier with a library such as [NCurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses).

Comment: @ArnavBorborah Its for a project so I cant use any libraries other than the default ones in windows :(

Comment: Possibly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6423729/get-current-cursor-position

Comment: Why not use the mouse? Windows can do mouse interaction in console windows.

Comment: Here is some Microsoft sample code that may help you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/reading-input-buffer-events

Comment: But to add to this, of course this isn't portable to other non-Windows machines. There is no portable C++ standard for anything beyond very simple text input and output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `BOOL GetConsoleSelectionInfo(PCONSOLE_SELECTION_INFO lpConsoleSelectionInfo)` from `windows.h`:

```
CONSOLE_SELECTION_INFO selectionInf;
GetConsoleSelectionInfo(&selectionInf);
```

members of structure `CONSOLE_SELECTION_INFO` :

1. `dwFlags`: `CONSOLE_NO_SELECTION`, `CONSOLE_SELECTION_IN_PROGRESS`, `CONSOLE_SELECTION_NOT_EMPTY`, `CONSOLE_MOUSE_SELECTION`, `CONSOLE_MOUSE_DOWN`
2. `dwSelectionAnchor`: structure `COORD` with `x` and `y` coordinates of selection (exactly what you need)
3. `srSelection`: structure `SMALL_RECT` with coordinates of selection's rectangle (`Left` and `Top`, `Right` and `Bottom`)