# DirectX 9 Get Cursor Position

Tags: c++, directx-9, cursor-position

So here's my problem: I want to get the cursor position which is in my directx 9 application. Not the default `GetCursorPos(&rect)`. It should only be the mouse position inside of my application so for example if I draw a Rect at 100, 100, 200, 200 and when I hover my mouse over the rect the mouse x and y should be somewhere between 100 and 200. Is there any function like
`myDevice->GetCursorPosition()`, because I only saw a `SetCursorPosition` method.

Comment: couldnt you just get the global mouse position and add the position of the rekt, so eg if you get 10,10 from `GetCursorPos(&rect)` inside a rect with min position 100,100, you could add the minimum width and height values to get the correct value?

Comment: but wouldn't there be some problems if I change the resolution

Comment: Sounds like you want to use [`ScreenToClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162952%28VS.85%29.aspx) as described here: [Get current cursor position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6423729/get-current-cursor-position)

Comment: @UnholySheep Thanks! Works fine. Could you please write this as an anwser so I could mark it as the best solution. Would be nice.

Comment: Since it already exists as an answer it should be closed as a duplicate instead